# Is there a Sentiment Analysis Script available in open source?

Tags: php, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for a sentiment analysis script / soyurce code preferably in PHP. Do you know of any such script?
Thanks, Sameer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP/ir is a great blog for this kind of stuff, and has a post on a [basic bayesian sentiment classifier](http://www.phpir.com/bayesian-opinion-mining).

Answer (score 9):

[phpInsight](https://github.com/JWHennessey/phpInsight) is an open source sentiment classifier in php based on the blog post recommended above.